# No value exists in scope for the shorthand property error when 'sanitizing' object

Tags: typescript

***No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'something'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)*** error when trying to remove some properties from an object by destructuring and returning `...rest`.

This solution gives me the error:

```
JSON.stringify(({ apikey, password, ...rest } = data) && rest)
```

This solution works, but would be nice to just 'inline/oneline' it:

```
const sanitize = (data: Data) => {
  const { apikey, password, ...rest } = data
  return rest
}
```

and then

```
JSON.stringify(sanitize(data))
```

Question: is it possible to declare or provide an initializer in the first solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not in the way you expect.

The **destructuring assignment** syntax works only when declaring variables, like:

```js
const [a, b] = [1, 2];
```

Or when assigning values to *already declared* variables:

```
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let a, b;
{ a, b } = obj;
```

> For more info, see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#try_it)

In your example, the following

```js
JSON.stringify(({ apikey, password, ...rest } = data) && rest)
```

Does not work because `apikey`, `password` and `rest` *do not exists* in the current scope, you should add them:

```js
let apikey, password, rest;
JSON.stringify(({ apikey, password, ...rest } = data) && rest);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to put it in one line of code, you can use an anonymous function and call it with the data you want to sanitize as part of the argument for `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const data = {
  apikey: 'KEY',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  prop1: '...',
  prop2: '...'
}
const sanitized = JSON.stringify((({ apikey, password, ...rest }) => (rest))(data))

console.log('sanitized', sanitized) // sanitized {"prop1":"...","prop2":"..."}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering I got it to work:

```
{JSON.stringify((({ apikey, password, ...rest }) => (rest))(data))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this subject, but what you are doing is a completely different thing.

You are extracting properties into variables from the data object:

```
({ apikey, password, ...rest } = data, rest)
```

I'm using an arrow function that takes the destructuring syntax as a parameter and immediately invoking it with `'data'` as an argument and just returning a new object:

```
(({ apikey, ...rest }) => (rest))(data) // returns an object without 'apikey'
```

Here is another example of the syntax I'm using:

```
((a, b) => (a+b))(2,3) // returns 5
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You MUST have a `rest` variable, otherwise `rest` will be assigned to `globalThis.rest`
2. Use "comma"`,` operator - it ignores all values except the last one (except in function arguments)

```
let a = 1, 2, 3; // let a = 3
let b = f(), g(), h(); // f(); g(); let b = h();
fn(  (1, 2, 3)  ); // fn(1)

let apikey, password, rest; // MUST have this or you'll write into globalThis
JSON.stringify(  ({ apikey, password, ...rest } = data, rest)  );
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? `let a = 1, 2, 3` raise a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Also, given `let f = (a) => a;`, the call `f((1, 2, 3))` returns `3`, not `1`